# Select values of a row based on whether other row is unique

Tags: r, dataframe

I would need to create a new column in my data, which would be equal to 'tender' value in case the 'id' appears only once, and to the 'lot' value in case it does not. I cannot do it through anything concerning NA, since the data is incomplete and there is a lot of NAs in there. My idea was to do it that if 'id' is unique, then select

```
df <- data.frame('id'=c(1,1,2,3,3,4), 
                 'lot'=c(10,20,NA,40,50,NA), 'tender'=c(30,30,30,90,90,40))
```

A am expecting the output to be:

```
data.frame('id'=c(1,1,2,3,3,4), 'lot'=c(10,20,NA,40,50,NA), 
           'tender'=c(30,30,30,90,90,40),'price'=c(10,20,30,40,50,40))
```

Comment: You may need `df %>% mutate(price = coalesce(lot, tender))`

Comment: Or if we go by the condition `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(price = case_when(n() ==1 ~ tender, TRUE ~ lot))`

Comment: Would not that just replace the NAs with the 'tender' value? I cannot do that, as I mentioned, there is a lot of NAs that are simply missing at random, not because the value of 'tender' belongs there.

Comment: I showeed two methods 1) based on the data, 2) based on the logic you mentioned

Comment: Yes  sorry, the second one wasnt there when I started writing :D

Comment: You can make it more robusst with an additional check `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(price = case_when(n() ==1 & is.na(lot) ~ tender, TRUE ~ lot))`  Let me know if that works

Comment: Can confirm it works, thanks! (my dataset is huge, it took like 5 mins to create the new column lol)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the condition, we can do a group by `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(price = case_when(n() ==1 & is.na(lot) ~ tender, TRUE ~ lot))
```

With the OP's current example, `coalesce` would also work

```
df %>%
   mutate(price = coalesce(lot, tender))
```

Comment: is there an advantage to using ```case_when``` here instead of ```ifelse```, or is it just a case of preference?

Comment: @RussThomas According to `?case_when` `This function allows you to vectorise multiple if_else() statements.`.  But, that was not the reason I used it here.  It was the first one my hands typed, so I followed it

Answer (score 2):

We can do this:

```
df$price <- apply(df, 1, function(x) min(x["lot"], x["tender"], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or in `dplyr` solution would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(price = min(lot, tender, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   id [4]
#      id   lot tender price
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    10     30    10
# 2     1    20     30    20
# 3     2    NA     30    30
# 4     3    40     90    40
# 5     3    50     90    50
# 6     4    NA     40    40
```

Comment: What if there is an `id` with 1 row, and `tender > lot` (as it is for all rows in the example data)?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I think `tender` is the cumulative (sort of) `lot` so I don't see the possibility of the case you presented. OP can verify/nullify this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this description, you can use an if statement on the group size with data.table

> I would need to create a new column in my data, which would be equal
>   to 'tender' value in case the 'id' appears only once, and to the 'lot'
>   value in case it does not.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, price := if(.N == 1) tender else lot, by = id]
#    id lot tender price
# 1:  1  10     30    10
# 2:  1  20     30    20
# 3:  2  NA     30    30
# 4:  3  40     90    40
# 5:  3  50     90    50
# 6:  4  NA     40    40
```